# java.lang.StackOverflowError - Guice and Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, guice

I mapped a servlet in my application like this with Google Guice:

```
protected void configureServlets() {
 serve("/_ah/*").with(DatastoreViewerServlet.class);
}
```

And I get this StackOverFlow error:

```
[ERROR] java.lang.StackOverflowError
[ERROR]     at java.lang.String.startsWith(String.java:1408)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.setAttribute(Dispatcher.java:427)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.removeAttribute(Dispatcher.java:461)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.setAttribute(Dispatcher.java:441)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.removeAttribute(Dispatcher.java:461)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.setAttribute(Dispatcher.java:441)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.removeAttribute(Dispatcher.java:461)
```

When the path is accessed, why is that?

Comment: Was this question solved? I have the same error..

Comment: @User-8017771 yes as far I as remember, actually what I  remember is that I actually removed Guice mapping on the root and just for the sub paths example /rest/* not /*